# What computer-assisted translation (CAT) software is available?

Tags: software-recommendation, translation

I am translator and I would like to know if there is any Computer Assisted Translation tool to use with Ubuntu. I've heard about programs such as Swordfish and so on. Does anybody know how is it and where can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

From the list shown on the wikipedia page for [Computer Assisted Translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-assisted_translation), I successfully used on Ubuntu :

- the local application [POEdit](http://www.poedit.net/) (in a single user context)
- the web server [Pootle](http://translate.sourceforge.net/wiki/pootle/index) (for a multi user/multi project context).

Answer (score 0):

[Omegat](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/natty/omegat/) comes to mind. It's a "free translation memory application written in Java. It is a tool intended for professional translators." [*(Source)*](http://www.omegat.org/en/omegat.html)

[image: Install via the software center]

Comment: This is a rather old version. I prefer downloading the latest version of this great Java application from here:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/omegat/files/OmegaT%20-%20Latest/OmegaT%202.6.0%20update%203/OmegaT_2.6.0_03_Beta_Without_JRE.zip/download